# html css page break

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
   
}

div.row { 
  page-break-after: always; 
}
```

```html
<body>

<div<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
     <p><h2>101</h2>
<img src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/33.64188,-84.50077/7?mapSize=500,500&pp=33.64188,-84.50077;21;1&pp=33.76768,-84.36031;;2&key=ArJkybJp6LvcJs7su6sKIQMBnwYngXlhGIjE5aWRApleSq6DkWzGNm5j80Lb-WZt">
<h6>YES/NO 1. x? </br>
YES/NO 2. x?</br>
YES/NO 3. x?</br>
YES/NO 4. x?</br>
YES/NO 5. x?</br>
YES/NO 6. x?</h6><h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date,</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5></p>
  </div>
 <div class="column" style="width: 1000; align: top;" >
    <p>
<table>
<tr><th>Stop Number</th><th>Address</th><th>Zip</th><th>Arrival</th>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td><td>2:30</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>
<td>4:00</td></tr>
</table>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
     <p><h2>02</h2>
<img src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/33.64188,-84.50077/7?mapSize=500,500&pp=33.64188,-84.50077;21;1&pp=33.76768,-84.36031;;2&key=ArJkybJp6LvcJs7su6sKIQMBnwYngXlhGIjE5aWRApleSq6DkWzGNm5j80Lb-WZt">
<h6>YES/NO 1. x? </br>
YES/NO 2. x?</br>
YES/NO 3. x?</br>
YES/NO 4. x?</br>
YES/NO 5. x?</br>
YES/NO 6. x?</h6><h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date,</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5>
<h5>________________________________________________________________________</br>
 Signature                                       Date</br></h5></p>
  </div>
 <div class="column" >
    <p>
<table>
<tr><th>Stop Number</th><th>Address</th><th>Zip</th><th>Arrival</th>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td><td>2:30</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td>
<td>11111</td>
<td>22222</td>
<td>4:00</td></tr>
</table>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>

</body>
```

I have a page with two columns and I need a page break after one section of code to print the other two columns on the next page. But I can only get the columns to appear one after the other next to each other. They look great. I just need the page break and I've tried both the empty div between the two "pages" with the accompanying CSS:

CSS

```
div.row { 
  page-break-after: always;
```

HTML

```
<div class="pagebreak"> </div>
```

and I've also tried

```
<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>
```

but instead of a page break after column 2 I end up with four columns and only one page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How does this question have 2 upvotes ?

Comment: @MihaiT By clicking twice on the up arrow above the number....

Comment: Try `<div class="row"> </div>` ? Or alternatively, make it `div.pagebreak { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

This property applies to block elements that generate a box. It won't apply on an empty div   that won't generate a box. Try Adding Some Content On You .row div